# Cannot read property '_id' of undefined unhandled Rejection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am moving from Class Components to Functional Components for some reason the last component is breaking the app.

There was a component DidMount before; that why I was trying to use useEffect refreshContent but if a take it out some features of the app stop working.

```
class UserSummary extends Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = initialState
  };

async componentDidMount() {
this.refreshContent();
}
```

Code Sample:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './UserSummary.css';
import todoService from '../../utils/todoService';
import EditTodoButton from '../EditTodoButton/EditTodoButton';

function UserSummary(props) {
  const [state, setState] = useState ({
    todo: {
      done: false
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    refreshContent();
  });

  async function refreshContent() {
    const todos = await todoService.index(props.user);
    console.log( "FIRST ", todos)
    props.handleUpdateTodos(todos);
  }

  async function handleDeleteToDo(todo){
    await todoService.deleteToDo(todo);
    refreshContent();
  }

  async function handleEditToDo(todo, updatedToDo){
    await todoService.editToDo(todo, updatedToDo);
    refreshContent();
  }

  async function handleUpdateToDo(todo) {
    let update = todo;
    if (update.done) {
      update.done = false
    } else {
      update.done = true
    }
    await todoService.doneToDo(todo);
    const todos = await todoService.index(props.user);
    props.handleUpdateTodos(todos);
  }

  function TodoRows() {
    const { todos } = props;
    const todoRows = todos.map((todo, index) => (
      <ul key={index}>
        <li className="ToDoList">
          <input type="checkbox" defaultValue={setState.done} name="done" checked={todo.done} onChange={() => handleUpdateToDo(todo)} />&nbsp;&nbsp;Done&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button onClick={() => handleDeleteToDo(todo)}><span role="img" aria-label="delete"></span></button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <EditTodoButton
            {...props}
            refreshContent={refreshContent}
            handleEditToDo={handleEditToDo}
            todo={state.todo} 
          />&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <span className="badge">{index + 1}</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          {todo.text}&nbsp;&nbsp;
          {todo.done}&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </li>
      </ul>
    ));
    return todoRows;
  }

    return (
      <div className='usersummary'>
        <br />
        <div className='user-cards' style={{ justifyContent: "center", }}>
          <div id='ToDoList'>
            <h3 className='header-footer'>To Do List</h3>
            <Link to="/newtodo">Add New To Do</Link>
            <br />
            {
              props.todos.length ? TodoRows() : ( <h5 className='text-info'>No To Do List Items Yet</h5> )
            }
          </div>
          <br />
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
}
export default UserSummary;
```

Here are some pictures trying to console.log the error.

```
[error][1]
[console.log][2]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjHnb.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uW6qk.png
```

Comment: Are you passing the user prop correctly? Can you please show the code where you're mounting the `UserSummary` component?

Comment: `import React from "react";
import UserSummary from "../../components/UserSummary/UserSummary";


function UserSummaryPage(props) {
  return (
    <div className="UserSummaryPage">
      <UserSummary
        {...props}
        user={props.user}
        todos={props.todos}
        handleUpdateTodos={props.handleUpdateTodos}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserSummaryPage;`. @MaddyBlacklisted

Answer (score 0):

`createToken` can return an error, but it doesn't reject the promise, instead the returned token will be null. You have to handle the error like this :

```
this.props.stripe.createToken({name : 'Name').then(({token, error}) => {
  if (error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle token
  }
});
```

If you do this, you should be able to find what the underlying error.

Comment: This may or may not solve your problem correctly since I only have a loose understanding of this, but I tried my best with the little knowledge I had.